# Compile time and runtime in C++

Tags: c++

If you created a variable of a primitive type like int, char, float inside a function, did you create that variable at runtime or at compile time?

If you created an object inside a function, did you create that object at runtime or at compile time?

If you create an object by memory allocation through heap, did you create that object at runtime or at compile time?

What is static memory allocation and dynamic memory allocation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you created a variable of a primitive type like int, char, float
>   inside a function. Did you create that variable at runtime or at
>   compile time?

You create the variable at run-time, the variable is created when the function is executed, and is destroyed when the function is finished.

> If you created an object inside a function. Did you create that object at runtime or at compile time?

Same as above.

> If you create an object by memory allocation thru heap. Did you create that object at runtime or at compile time?

If you're creating an object on the heap, you're essentially allocating the memory at runtime and get returned a pointer to it.  With this pointer, you can read/write to this memory.

Static memory, is memory that only be read from at runtime.

Dynamic memory allocation, refers to allocating objects on the heap and changing them through a pointer to the memory.

Comment: So no variable and objects created at compile time? so then what are the things created at compile time? They say that inheritance is at compile time and polymorphism and composition is at runtime what does this mean? Dont worry I understand polymorphism and composition so no need to explain that. THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: My understanding is that static variables anything that is stored as part of the program binary (i.e. code, variables marked static, constants). Everything else is created at run-time.

Comment: Thanks david, constants you mean string literals numeric literals??

Comment: Yes that is my understanding. Variables marked static, etc. are known and allocated during compile type and stored in [.bss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) and .text sections of memory

Answer (score 2):

No, the `const int a=42;` //a is created at the compile time and not at run time.

Answer (score 1):

on c++ 11

`constexpr` tells the compiler that this is a **compile** time constant, not allocated, used by value when needed and subject to optimizations, expressions involving `constexpr` and/or `const` values are calculated at compile time.
Compilers can do otherwise, but i see no need for even large `constexpr` objects to be allocated whatsoever.

`const` allocated at **compile** time can be optimized by using value when needed if no pointer taken

global variables and static variables inside functions are allocated at **compile** time

variables inside functions are usually put into **stack** memory, same as passing arguments, but they can reside on memory (compiler is free i guess)

things allocated with `new` operator (or old C style `malloc`) will reside on **heap** until freed